# Spring security 4 : Access denied on providing roles

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

Code was working fine now have replaced the below line in security.xml to provide role based security, but getting **access denied http status-403**

Replaced

```
<intercept-url pattern="/inputcreate*" access="isAuthenticated()" />
```

with

```
<intercept-url pattern="/inputcreate*" access="hasAnyRole('admin','user')" />
```

spring-security.xml

```
<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <!-- <intercept-url pattern="/inputcreate*" access="isAuthenticated()" /> -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/inputcreate*" access="hasAnyRole('admin','user')" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/inputcreate.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.html" username-parameter="j_username"
        password-parameter="j_password" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check" />
    <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout"
        logout-success-url="/index.html" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 2):

just Replaced

```
<intercept-url pattern="/inputcreate*" access="hasAnyRole('admin','user')" />
```

with

```
<intercept-url pattern="/inputcreate*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER')" />
```

After googling 3-4 hour,  made this above change
This worked for me!!!!

In the Spring documentation it has been given here, **to prefix role**

```
public void setRolePrefix(String rolePrefix)
Allows a default role prefix to be specified. If this is set to a non-empty value, then it is automatically prepended to any roles read in from the db. 
This may for example be used to add the ROLE_ prefix expected to exist in role names (by default) by some other Spring Security classes, in the case that the prefix is not already present in the db.

        Parameters:
        rolePrefix - the new prefix
```

Comment: also change the corresponding values in your role table.